# mainloop problem python /raspberry pi / based swamp cooler thermostat

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Hello I am new to coding, I've been learning through tutorials/ and random reddit posts and other forums. I decided to do something that I needed for my home for my first project a thermostat that could turn the swamp cooler on and off automatically. my swamp cooler has three wires 1, 2, L1, C these wires are connected to a 115v 15amp relay switch that is controlled by the raspberry pi GPIO pins. I tried to figure it out on my own for as much as possible but I think I have reached an wall.

Desired Functionality:
Ideally the program should ask for a name, to set a desired temperature between 50 and 80 degrees F and throw and error if a number outside that range is entered. It is then supposed to check the DHT22 sensor for the actual temperature and compare that to the temperature the thermostat was set to and either turn on the pump and the high fan or stay idle until the temp has changed.

the code is stopping after I enter the temperature and giving me the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "thermosv5.py", line 36, in 
Set_temp = int (input (name + " Please enter your desired temperature between 50°F and 80°F "))
TypeError: 'range' object is not callable

Anyone have any pointers or ideas on what I should do to make this functional?

Edited...

```
import time
import Adafruit_DHT
import sys
import gpiozero

# Triggered by the output pin going high: active_high=True.

#GPIO Pinout
PRIME_PUMP = 7
LOW_VENT = 5
HIGH_VENT = 3

#This tells us which GPIO Pin triggers a corresponding relay 
relay2 = gpiozero.OutputDevice(PRIME_PUMP, active_high=True, initial_value=False)
relay1 = gpiozero.OutputDevice(LOW_VENT, active_high=True, initial_value=False)
relay3 = gpiozero.OutputDevice(HIGH_VENT, active_high=True, initial_value=False)

# DHT11 is the module used to take temperature measurments
DHT_SENSOR = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
DHT_PIN = 17

# Time to prime the pad in seconds
PRIMETIME=5
PRINTTIME=5
PRIMED=0

#This code creates variables with the sensor information from the DHT22 module connected on GPIO pin 17
humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read(DHT_SENSOR, DHT_PIN)

#this code will validate if a user has entered a temperature with-in the allowed temperature range 
Temp_range = int = range(50,81)

name = input("Hello Please Enter Your Name: ")
print("Welcome " + name +"!")

Set_temp = int (input (name + " Please enter your desired temperature between 50°F and 80°F ")) 
if Set_temp == Temp_range:
    print (Set_temp + "°F has been set")
    PRINTTIME
    print (temperature + "°F")
else:
    print ("Invalid input temperature value. The desired temperature must be between 50°F and 80°F")

def set_Relay():
        print("Powering: ON")

def prime_Pad():
        print ("Priming Pads")
        relay2.on()
        time.sleep(PRIMETIME)
        print ("Priming Pad's done")
        relay2.off()

def prime_pad_Off():
        relay2.off()

def high_Cool():
        print ("High Cool On")
        relay3.on()
        relay2.on()
def high_cool_off():
        relay3.off()
        relay2.off()

def low_Cool():
        print ("Low Cool On")
        relay1.on()
        relay2.on()

def low_cool_Off():
        relay1.off()
        relay2.off()

def low_Vent():
        print("Fan on low")
        relay1.on()

def high_Vent():
        print ("Fan on High")
        relay3.on()

def high_vent_Off():
        relay3.off()

def is_tempMet(temperature,Set_temp):
    while (temperature <= Set_temp):
        return True 

def prime_Option():
        if temperature < Set_temp:
           prime_Pad()
        else:
           print("Priming is not necessary")

def Main_loop():
        while (is_tempMet == True):
           print("Cooling Cycle Running")
           high_Cool()
        else:
           print("Desired Temperature met")
           high_cool_off()

# program logic starts here
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        set_Relay()
        name
        Set_temp
        prime_Option()
        Main_loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nExiting application\n")
        # exit the application
        sys.exit(0)
```

updated code

```
import time
import Adafruit_DHT
import sys
import gpiozero

# Triggered by the output pin going high: active_high=True.

#GPIO Pinout
PRIME_PUMP = 7
LOW_VENT = 5
HIGH_VENT = 3

#This tells us which GPIO Pin triggers a corresponding relay 
relay2 = gpiozero.OutputDevice(PRIME_PUMP, active_high=True, initial_value=False)
relay1 = gpiozero.OutputDevice(LOW_VENT, active_high=True, initial_value=False)
relay3 = gpiozero.OutputDevice(HIGH_VENT, active_high=True, initial_value=False)

# DHT11 is the module used to take temperature measurments
DHT_SENSOR = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
DHT_PIN = 17

# Time to prime the pad in seconds
PRIMETIME=5
PRINTTIME=5
PRIMED=0

#This code creates variables with the sensor information from the DHT22 module connected on GPIO pin 17 and then converts the temperature reading into a float number
humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read(DHT_SENSOR, DHT_PIN)
print("Temp={0:0.1f}f Humidity={1:0.1f}%".format(temperature * 1.8 + 32, humidity))
temperature = float()
humidity = float()

name = input("Hello Please Enter Your Name: ")
print("Welcome " + name +"!")

Set_temp = float (input(name + " Please enter your desired temperature between 50°F and 80°F ")) 
while (50 <= Set_temp <= 80):
    print(Set_temp)
    break
else:
    print ("Invalid input temperature value. The desired temperature must be between 50°F and 80°F")

def set_Relay():
        print("Powering: ON")

def prime_Pad():
        print ("Priming Pads")
        relay2.on()
        time.sleep(PRIMETIME)
        print ("Priming Pad's done")
        relay2.off()

def prime_pad_Off():
        relay2.off()

def high_Cool():
        print ("High Cool On")
        relay3.on()
        relay2.on()
def high_cool_off():
        relay3.off()
        relay2.off()

def low_Cool():
        print ("Low Cool On")
        relay1.on()
        relay2.on()

def low_cool_Off():
        relay1.off()
        relay2.off()

def low_Vent():
        print("Fan on low")
        relay1.on()

def high_Vent():
        print ("Fan on High")
        relay3.on()

def high_vent_Off():
        relay3.off()
       
def prime_Option():
        if temperature > Set_temp:
           prime_Pad()
        else:
           print("Priming is not necessary")

def is_tempMet():
    while (Set_temp >= temperature):
        return True 

def Main_loop():
        while (is_tempMet == True):
           print("Cooling Cycle Running")
           high_Cool()
        else:
           print("Desired Temperature met")
           high_cool_off()

def Idle_loop():
    while (temperature <= Set_temp):
            print (temperature)
    else:
       Main_loop()

# program logic starts here
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        name
        Set_temp
        prime_Option()
        Main_loop()
        Idle_loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nExiting application\n")
        # exit the application
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: A first look shows two problems: You are missing a closing `)` in the line starting with `Set_temp = `. A few lines below there is also an additional `"` in `print (temperature + "°F"")`.

Comment: your right I over looked a few things. I've reworked the code.

Comment: Your temperature validation does not work the way you think. The line `Temp_range = int = range(50,81)` assigns a range object to `int` which breaks everything using `int`. You do not need that line anyway: Instead of testing `if Set_temp == Temp_range` (which will always be False, since you are comparing an integer to a range object), do this: `if 50 <= Set_temp <= 80:`

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I am now running the program without any errors. I do have one last issue it seems like the variable "temperature" is not using the temperature reading from my DHT22 module for some reason and is returning 0.0 as a temperature value which causes the program to stay idle. If I understand correctly this code should create the variable "temperature" from the DHT22 sensor and turn the value into a float to compare with the Set_Temp variable which is also a float ```temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read(DHT_SENSOR, DHT_PIN)
temperature = float() ```

Comment: ```humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read(DHT_SENSOR, DHT_PIN)
print("Temp={0:0.1f}f Humidity={1:0.1f}%".format(temperature * 1.8 + 32, humidity))
temperature = float()
humidity = float()```

Comment: The lines `temperature = float()` and `humidity = float()` set the values to zero. They are not required. Just remove them.